# How do I mention a user in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to code a simple bot using discord.py, so I started with the fun commands to get familiar with the library.

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!hug'):
        await message.channel.send(f"hugs {message.author.mention}")

    if message.content.startswith('!best'):
        user_id = "201909896357216256"
        user_mention = ???  # How to convert user_id into a mention
        await message.channel.send(f'{user_mention} is the best')
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

So I finally figured out how to do this after few days of trial and error hoping others would benefit from this and have less pain than I actually had..
The solution was ultimately easy..

```
  if message.content.startswith('!best'):
        myid = '<@201909896357216256>'
        await client.send_message(message.channel, ' : %s is the best ' % myid)
```

Answer (score 18):

Updated answer for discord.py 1.x - 2.x (2021):

Some of the other solutions are now obsolete since discord.py's syntaxes has changed and the old versions no longer works.

If you only have the user ID, then it's:

```
user_id = "201909896357216256"
await message.channel.send(f"<@{user_id}> is the best")
```

If you have the user/member object, then it's:

```
await message.channel.send(f"{user.mention} is the best")
```

If you only have the user name and discriminator (the bot and user must share a server and members cache must be toggled on):

```
user = discord.utils.get(client.users, name="USERNAME", discriminator="1234")
if user is None:
    print("User not found")
else:
    await message.channel.send(f"{user.mention} is the best")
```

Replace `message.channel` if you have a `ctx` when using commands instead of `on_message`.

Answer (score 7):

If you're working on commands, you're best to use discord.py's built in command functions, your hug command will become:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@commands.command(pass_context=True)
async def hug(self, ctx):
    await self.bot.say("hugs {}".format(ctx.message.author.mention))
```

This is assuming you've done something like this at the start of your code:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.bot = discord.Client(#blah)
```

Comment: I had this error :  ```await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "alfred-bot.py", line 69, in on_message
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable``` when trying to send a message using .author.mention(), but solved removing the () from mention

Answer (score 4):

From a `User` object, use the attribute `User.mention` to get a string that represents a mention for the user. To get a user object from their ID, you need `Client.get_user_info(id)`. To get the a user from a username ('ZERO') and discriminator ('#6885') use the utility function `discord.utils.get(iterable, **attrs)`. In context:

```
if message.content.startswith('!best'):
    user = discord.utils.get(message.server.members, name = 'ZERO', discriminator = 6885)
    # user = client.get_user_info(id) is used to get User from ID, but OP doesn't need that
    await client.send_message(message.channel, user.mention + ' mentioned')
```

Comment: File "\client.py", line 307, in _run_event yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bot.py", line 39, in on_message  
    id = User.id('ZERO#6885').format(message) # or whatever you're doing to get id
NameError: name 'User' is not defined

Comment: @ItachiSama Upon further reading, you actually don't have the user's ID: you have their username and discriminator. I've changed the code to reflect that and left the method that will work if you have the ID in a comment.

Comment: I cant thank you enough for all the effort you've don but it actually took me over 5 hours reading docs and searching online just to mention an id or username, the new code is giving me this error

Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "it.py", line 48, in on_message
    await client.send_message(message.channel, user.mention() + ' mentioned')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mention'

Answer (score 3):

**If you just want to respond from the on_message callback, you can grab the mention string from the author like so:**

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    # No infinite bot loops
    if message.author == bot.user or message.author.bot:
        return

    mention = message.author.mention
    response = f"hey {mention}, you're great!"
    await message.channel.send(response)
```

Answer (score 2):

While OP's issue is long resolved (and likely forgotten) -- If you're building a Discord bot in Python, it's still a bit difficult to find this information - hopefully this helps someone. 
If you're trying to use the @bot.command method - the following will work (in python3):

```
@bot.command(name='ping', help='Ping the bot to text name')
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Pong ' + format(ctx.author))
    print("debug: " + dir(ctx.author))
```

If you want to display the **nickname** of the "author" (who called the command) you can use this instead":

```
@bot.command(name='ping', help='Ping the bot to text name')
async def ping(ctx):
    # await ctx.send('Pong {0}'.format(ctx.author))
    await ctx.send('Pong ' + format(ctx.author.display_name))
    print("debug: " + dir(ctx.author))
```

Another helpful tip:
You can use `dir(ctx.author)` to see the *attributes* of the `ctx.author` *object*.