# How can I tag a member in my python discord bot

Tags: python, discord

So I have this leveling system in python but I wanna add an @tag so the bot mentions the member that leveled up... But I got no idea how. I already tried multiple things but they all don't work.

```
    from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import logging
import yaml
import sqlite3
import time
import random
import re

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='l>', description='Hype Levels')

def threshold(n):
    level_threshold = 5*(n**2)+50*n+100
    return level_threshold

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def rank(ctx):

    try:
        _, member = (ctx.message.content).split(' ', 1)
        member = re.sub("[^0-9]", "", member)
    except:
        member = ctx.message.author.id

    db = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
    c = db.cursor()

    c.execute('SELECT user.*, (SELECT count(*) FROM users AS members WHERE members.rawexp > user.rawexp) as Rank FROM users AS user WHERE id = ?',
              (ctx.message.author.id, ))

    user = c.fetchone()
    db.close()

    rank = str(user[6] + 1)

    embed = discord.Embed(title='{}\'s Information'.format(ctx.message.author.name)) \
            .set_thumbnail(url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url) \
            .add_field(name='Rank', value='#' + rank) \
            .add_field(name='Level', value=user[2]) \
            .add_field(name='EXP', value='{}/{}'.format(user[3], threshold(user[2]))) \
            .add_field(name='Raw EXP', value=user[4]) \

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    if message.author.bot:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('l>'):
        await bot.process_commands(message)
        return

    db = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
    c = db.cursor()

    c.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id= ?', (message.author.id,))
    user = c.fetchone()

    if user is None:
        await message.channel.send('Looks like you\'re new! Welcome to level 1. Initializing player...')
        c.execute('INSERT INTO users(id, name, level, exp, rawexp, time) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)', (message.author.id, message.author.name, 1, 0, 0, time.time()))
        db.commit()
        db.close()
        return

    if message.author.name != user[1]:
        c.execute('UPDATE users SET name = ? WHERE id= ?', (message.author.name, message.author.id))

    if (time.time() - user[5]) > 60:
        addedexp = random.randint(10, 25)
        exp = user[3] + addedexp
        rawexp = user[4] + addedexp
        c.execute('UPDATE users SET exp = ?, rawexp = ?, name = ?, time = ? WHERE id= ?', (exp, rawexp, message.author.name, time.time(), message.author.id))

        if (exp > threshold(user[2])):
            level = user[2] + 1
            c.execute('UPDATE users SET exp = ?, level = ? WHERE id= ?', (0, level, message.author.id))
            await message.channel.send('Wowza! You leveled up! Your level is now **{}**.'.format(level))


    db.commit()
    db.close()

    await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("HypeLevels V1.1")
    print("Made by: Garbodonk#6347")
    print("Bot Name: " + str(bot.user.name))
    print("Bot ID: " + str(bot.user.id))
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name='some HYPE', url="https://www.twitch.tv/hypepixelbot", type=1))

    #Initialize database.
    db = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, level INT, exp INTEGER, rawexp INTEGER, time REAL)')
    db.commit()

bot.run('Token')
```

But I want to add an @tag when people level up so they get tagged

```
if (exp > threshold(user[2])):
            level = user[2] + 1
            c.execute('UPDATE users SET exp = ?, level = ? WHERE id= ?', (0, level, message.author.id))
            await message.channel.send('Wowza! You leveled up! Your level is now **{}**.'.format(level))
```

anyone who knows how to do this? To ask me questions or something just add me on discord: Garbodonk#6347

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do i mention a user using user's id in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43964328/how-do-i-mention-a-user-using-users-id-in-discord-py)

Answer (score 0):

````
async def command(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None) :
         await ctx.send(f" can place text here if you want {member.mention} can place text here as well")```

I hope this helps.
````