# Writing a discord welcome command (discord.py) on python 3.6

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hey so right now I'm trying to make it so that whenever a member joins it just @'s them then tells them to go to some channels but right now it just comes out as text without @'ing them or highlighting the channels

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f'{member} has joined the server.')
    channel = client.get_channel(724748520292352046)
    await channel.send(f'Welcome @{member} to The Server! Make sure to read #rules and get yourself some roles from #react-roles')
```

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43964328/how-do-i-mention-a-user-using-users-id-in-discord-py

Comment: That seems to work but know how would I get that members id?

Comment: You get the member id with `member_id = str(member.id)` If your argument is message then us `member_id = str(message.author.id)`

Answer (score 0):

To have it tag a member you need to use the `.mention` function of a member object.
So it would be `await channel.send(f'Welcome {member.mention} to The Server! Make sure to read #rules and get yourself some roles from #react-roles')`

I would also recommend changing the #rules and #react-roles to a channel.mention too. You just need the channel object of each which you can get from their ids.