# How do I mention someone using discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to mention a role in my discord bot using discord.py. I want my bot to mention a role when someone uses the !search command. How may I do this?

Comment: Does this question help at all? [how do i mention a user using user's id in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43964328/how-do-i-mention-a-user-using-users-id-in-discord-py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this to mention roles

```
@client.command()
async def search(ctx):
    await ctx.send(discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Role Name").mention)
```

Answer (score 0):

`ctx.author` gets the user who wrote the message. Using `ctx.author.mention` in a message mentions the user. Here's an example:

```
@client.command()
async def sayhi(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"Hi, {ctx.author.mention}!")
```

If you want to mention a role, use `role.mention`. You can get a role using `discord.utils.get()`. For more information on that, here's the link to the documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20utils%20get#discord.utils.get