# How to make a requested by <@user>

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I want to make a requested by <@user> on my discord bot. What I mean is when someone uses a command on the bot, for it to say in embed who used the command. (discord.py)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I mention a user using user's id in discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43964328/how-do-i-mention-a-user-using-users-id-in-discord-py)

Answer (score 1):

According to [the API Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.User.mention), a message has an `author` which is of type [`User`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.User). That user has a method named [`mention`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.User.mention) which returns a string you can use to mention the person using the command.

Given that you've set up your Discord client properly you should be able to do something like this:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@commands.command(pass_context=True)
async def hug(self, ctx):
    await self.bot.say("hugs {}".format(ctx.message.author.mention()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in many ways. You need to check who executed the command for example.

To get a user we can simply use something like `user = ctx.author`.

**It could look like this:**

```py
user = ctx.author
embed = discord.Embed()
embed.description = f"Requested by: {user.mention}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the `commands.ext.Bot` instance setup properly, you could try this:

```py
@bot.command
async def command_name(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="User mentioned")
    embed.add_field(name="Used by:", value=ctx.author.mention)
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```