# Python Discord Bot @'ing people

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I need when I run a command like `/insult @name` the bot @'s the person in the argument of the command and sends an image. I can do most of the rest but I can't seem to figure out of to have it `@mention` the person.

Comment: This will help [How do I mention a user using user's id in discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43964328/how-do-i-mention-a-user-using-users-id-in-discord-py)

Answer (score 3):

To mention a user in a command, you can use `member: discord.Member`. This helps you get a member object in the command itself. You can view more on how you can use a [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20member#discord.Member) object here. An example on how to use this in a command can also be found in the docs, view this: [`Discord Converters`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#discord-converters).

You can view how these can be incorporated below, including a `None` variable as a default to avoid errors in your console if the [`ctx.author`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.author) does not mention a member.

```py
@client.command() # or bot.command(), or whatever you're using
async def insult(ctx, member:discord.Member=None):
    if member == None: # Happens if ctx.author does not mention a member..
        member = ctx.author # ..so by default the member will be ctx.author
    # You can use member.mention to mention/ ping/ @ the person assigned as member
    await ctx.send(f"Be insulted {member.mention}!")
    # A not as good way to do it would be:
    await ctx.send(f"Be insulted <@{member.id}>!")
    # both methods work the same way, but member.mention is recommended
```

[image: Above code working]