# How do I make a custom discord bot @ someone that a person @ed in the command?

Tags: python, discord.py

When I type !best it comes up with my username which also does it if I @ someone else with the same command like !best @example and comes up with @nottheexample

```
if message.content.startswith('!best'):
        await message.channel.send(message.author.mention)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I mention a user using user's id in discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43964328/how-do-i-mention-a-user-using-users-id-in-discord-py)

Comment: no it doesnt i already tried that @Dominik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To mention a user you have to define it beforehand. You do this as follows:

```py
user = message.mentions[0]
```

To mention the user you can either use `f`-strings or `format`.

**Based on the code above here is an example:**

```py
@client.event # Or whatever you use
async def on_message(message):
    user = message.mentions[0]
    if message.content.startswith('!best'):
        await message.channel.send("Hello, {}".format(user.mention))
```

Please note that the code only works if you then also specify a `user`. However, you can add more `if` or `else` statements if you want to handle it differently.

Comment: Doesnt work it comes up with an error: ```Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 60, in on_message
    user = message.mentions[0]
IndexError: list index out of range ```

Comment: https://replit.com/join/urbrvhrrzi-cameronbutcher1 here is the full code

Comment: @CameronButcher "*Please note that the code only works if you then also specify a user*". You also can't have multiple `on_message` events and have to pay attention to the indentation

Answer (score 0):

`message.author.mention` always mentions the author of the message

you can solve this in multiple ways

1. Just send whatever comes behind `!best`

```py
if message.content.startswith('!best'):
    args = message.content.split('!best ')
    if len(args) > 1:
        await message.channel.send(args[1])
    else:
        await message.channel.send(message.author.mention)
```

2. same as number 1, but add some check if the thing behind `!best` is a real member - see [`Utility Functions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#utility-functions) in the docs

```py
member = discord.utils.find(lambda m: m.name == args[1], message.guild.members)

member = discord.utils.get(message.guild.members, name=agrs[1])
```

3. Use [Commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html) - I really recommend this one

```py
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command()
async def best(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        member = ctx.author
    await ctx.send(member.mention)
```

Comment: the 1st one works but i need it to do is when i say >example0: !best @example1> i want it to say> @example1

Comment: i dont unterstand, does it work or not? 

Comment: okay, can you please edit your questions with some more explenation of what the output should look like (maybe add som screenshots)? :D