# Getting the userid of a user that was tagged

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I am using discordpy to build a discord bot. One of the features that I want it to have, is to be able to give a random percentage about a user.

Example:

user1: !w @user2

bot: @user2 is x% y

I am unsure how to draw the userid of user2 from the message sent by user1. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you heard about `discord.Member`? With this you will be able to display the name/ID. Link: [Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20member#discord.Member)

Comment: You can use `message.mentions` to get a list of members who were mentioned in a message as `Member` objects, then you can do `Member.id` to get their user id

Comment: Thank you, but after looking through the documentation, I am still unsure how to implement it. Here is my code,


  if message.content.startswith('w!cool their id'):
    await message.channel.send('the persons id is cool')

Comment: Is this helping you then? [How do I make a custom discord bot @ someone that a person @ed in the command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68192998/how-do-i-make-a-custom-discord-bot-someone-that-a-person-ed-in-the-command/68193353#68193353)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`id` attribute](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.id) of [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#member).

### Example:

```py
@bot.command()
def w(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    user_id = user.id
    print(user_id)
```

---

Comment: If you look into the comments it looks like he wants to use the `on_message`-event, not a command.

Answer (score 0):

You've asked a question in the title and the description doesn't match it ;-;

Here's a basic code according to what you've asked in the description, customize it as you like :)

Make sure to replace 'client' with whatever you've used

```
@client.command()
async def cool(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
    pctg = (random.randint(0, 100))
    if user == None:
        await ctx.send('Mention a user')
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"{user.name} is {pctg}% cool")
```

If you want the mentioned user's ID as bot's reply then use the following -

```
@client.command()
async def uid(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    uid = user.id
    await ctx.send(uid)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you look into the comments it looks like he wants to use the `on_message`-event, not a command.

Comment: I think using a command would be more convenient for this but anyways I'll see if I can make some changes to answer.

Comment: I tried and I really think using command is better for this :')

Answer (score 0):

````py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('w!cool '):
        if message.mentions == []:
            await message.channel.send("You should mention someone!\n```\nw!cool <mention>\n```")
            return
        coolness_tosend=""
        for i in message.mentions:
            coolness_tosend=coolness_tosend+"<@" + str(i.id) + "> is " + str(random.choice(range(100))) + "\% cool.\n"
        await message.channel.send(coolness_tosend)
````

Links:

[discord.Message.mentions in API reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=client#discord.Message.mentions)

[discord.Message in API reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=client#discord.Message)

Do note, though, that `w!cool` alone without arguments won't work. It prevents conflict with commands such as `w!coolpic`. Don't forget to do an `import random`!

Answer (score 0):

````py
WCOOL_NO_MENTION_ERROR = "You should mention someone!\n" \
                       + "```\n" \
                       + "w!cool <mention> ...\n" \
                       + "```"

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('w!cool '):
        if not message.mentions:
            return await message.channel.send(WCOOL_NO_MENTION_ERROR)
        
        # Create a string for the response
        response = str()
        
        for mention in message.mentions:
            percentage = random.choice(range(0, 100+1))
            response += f"<@{mention.id}> is {percentage}% cool."
            response += "\n"
        
        await message.channel.send(response)
    elif message.content == "w!cool":
        return await message.channel.send(WCOOL_NO_MENTION_ERROR)
````

Based on my older answer from my other account but it's a little bit more readable. It works pretty much the same way with some things improved (such as caring about the situation when nothing comes after `w!cool`)

Also if anyone is reading this, don't use discord.py! It is unmaintained, so use a fork of it, such as Pycord.