# how to mention users with discord bot in python

Tags: python, discord, bots, member, mention

```
if message.content.startswith('!highfive'):
        channel = message.channel

        await channel.send('{0.author.mention} wants to high-five you'.format(message))

        def check(m):
            return m.content == 'yes' and m.channel == channel
      
        try:

            message = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=10.0, check=check)
            await channel.send('you accepted the highfive {0.author.mention}'.format(message))
            
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await channel.send('you took too long to answer')
```

Hi, I am very new to this and am trying to create a simple discord bot

I can get the bot to mention the author however, I have spent ages looking and still can't figure out how to mention users. I'd like to use the command '!highfive @(mentioned user)' and gain the response from the bot '@(author mentioned) wants to high-five you @(mentioned user)'

additionally, I can't generate separate responses to 'yes' and ideally, 'no' as well, without the timeout error not working.

thank you in advance to any help

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43964328/how-do-i-mention-a-user-using-users-id-in-discord-py) thread help you

Answer (score 0):

I am using **user id** to mention someone in my bot :

```py
import string #very important import to send message with 'f' text function

if message.content.startswith('!highfive'):
        channel = message.channel
        user_id = message.author.id  #getting author id

        await channel.send(f'<@{user_id}> wants to high-five you'.format(message)) #i eddited this to use 'user_id' variable to mention user

        def check(m):
            return m.content == 'yes' and m.channel == channel
      
        try:

            message = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=10.0, check=check)
            await channel.send(f'you accepted the highfive <@{user_id}>'.format(message)) #mention eddit here too
            
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await channel.send('you took too long to answer')
```